# How do I get WordPress posts from a specific date?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am unable to figure out how to retrieve WordPress posts from a specific date to the present date.

The following is the URL for getting all posts:

```
[<Literal>]
let private APIBaseAddress =   "https://public-api.wordpress.com/"

[<Literal>]
let private ArticlesUrl =      "rest/v1/sites/{0}/posts?number=100&page={1}"
```

Comment: Have you bothered to look at the API documentation? I assume not because it's right in there, where you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of all of the parameters can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/).

Add the `after` parameter.

```
let private ArticlesUrl = "rest/v1/sites/{0}/posts?number=100&page={1}&after=yyyymmdd"
```